# Disconnect Laptop Screen, What happens?

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, display

basically i have two external monitors plugged into my laptop and when i bootup, the laptop defaults to the laptop screen. i was thinking, if i unplugged the laptop screen, would one of the two external monitors default? or would the laptop still output to the non existant screen?

Comment: "Unplugged the laptop screen"? o___o

Comment: Have you got the answer? I have the same question

Answer (score 2):

There will probably be a setting in the laptop's BIOS to select the default display at bootup.

Accessing the BIOS will either be pressing F2 or DEL during the first stages of bootup (look for a message like "Press F2 to enter Setup" or something similar)

Most BIOS systems are fairly simple to navigate being largely menu driven.

If you can't find an entry in the BIOS for it there may be a program available from the laptop manufacturer which allows you to set various boot-time defaults like which screen to use.

I guess by "unplug the laptop screen" you mean opening up the laptop and pulling out cables connected to the motherboard?  I wouldn't even go near that area if I were you - you can't be sure what other things might be using the same connectors or what damage may be caused by running the laptop's video hardware with no screen attached (laptop screens often have a high voltage portion for the back-light)

Comment: my laptop has no such options in the bios :S i checked countless times and even looked into hacked bioses but no luck

Answer (score 0):

Try right-clicking on the desktop and checking your display properties.  Depending on you display driver. You may be able to save the default multi-head settings.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which OS you run, you may be able to specify which monitor is the primary monitor in the Display Settings.

You also may want to check any vendor-specific display utilities that came with your laptop.  My Dell laptop has a Dell utility that allows me to define multiple monitor configurations that are auto-set depending on whether or not it's docked.  An old Thinkpad I used to have had a similar utility.  I've setup my docked configurations to make the external display be the primary monitor, so the Windows taskbar appears there whenever docked without me having to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it's usually not an option to have both of the external screens going. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/501379/cant-use-both-display-outputs-on-xps-laptop

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-control-center/+bug/1304627

From what I understand the problem is that the 2 inputs are usually connected to separate graphics cards (nvidia vs intel-integrated), so I doubt turning off the builtin display would help.